# ReactJS, NodeJS deployment issue on linux server where application was coded in windows

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-administration

I have a web application created using ReactJS , NodeJS and Mongo DB on windows. And I am facing issues while deploying the same application on a Linux Server in AWS. Is there any changes to be considered while deploying such?

Is there any changes that needs to be done for the code? Does the path declaration change on the config file?

getting such errors? ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/ec2-user/Project/Backend/Backend/client/build/index.html'"

Comment: did you try deleting the build folder and rebuild ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you? Is there any changes that need to be done on the coding section?

Comment: No. there isn't usually any thing inside the code that needs to be changed. From the error you provided it seems that your build was not complete successful. it may happen becaues of some wrong import. when we work with multiple projects in the same ide it happens sometime. So you check if your files have any wrong import .If not then try deleting the project and re build from scratch

Comment: the code has been created and has been given to be to be hosted. I have little knowledge on React and Node. How do I continue

Comment: Is there any converter to convert it to support linux or what should I tell the developer to change?

Comment: what do you mean by the code has been created ? have you run any command like yarn build or npm run build inside the src folder ?

Comment: No Mohammad, I am asking is there any major changes that need to be done in the codes. ?

Comment: No.  There Isn't anything to be changed in code. Id it runs on windows it should run on linux

Comment: Then I guess its a dependency errors??

Comment: Its a build error.